# SwiftUI Completion Logic in View onAppear

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, state, completionhandler

I am fairly new to SwiftUI.

In this example I am running a network request through an API that has a completion handler in order to alter the app state, i.e., show a different view based on a tokens (JWT) validity. I am trying to figure out how to use the completion in the .onAppear of my view to do this, any help would be appreciated:

**View code**

```
struct LaunchView: View {

let keychainManager = KeychainManager()
let keychainRecords = KeychainRecords()
let tokenManager = TokenManager()

var validSession: Bool

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if validSession {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
    .onAppear(){
        do {
            let token = try keychainManager.getToken(identifier: keychainRecords.identifier, service: keychainRecords.service)
            
            let tokenValidationResponse = try tokenManager.validateToken(token: token){ completion in
                if Result<TokenValidationResponse, NetworkError> {
                    guard let message = tokenValidationResponse.Message else { return }
                    
                    if (message == "Success") {
                        validSession = true
                    } else {
                        validSession = false
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    // Show an error message
                    print("Network request failed")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Validation code**

```
func validateToken(token: String, completion: @escaping (Result<TokenValidationResponse, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        
    guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL + TOKEN) else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    
    let body = TokenRequestBody(token: token)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(.noData))
            return
        }
        
        guard let tokenValidationResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TokenValidationResponse.self, from: data) else {
            completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            return
        }
        print(tokenValidationResponse)
        completion(.success(tokenValidationResponse))
        
    }.resume()
}
```

Thank you (PS I am getting a valid response from the request when printed)

Comment: All of your `let` variables will get recreated every time the `View` is re-evaluated. You should do some reading on `@State` and `@StateObject` and learn state management in SwiftUI. Also, you'll probably want to use async/await in your validation function, either inside the `View` or perhaps inside of an `ObservableObject`

Comment: Hi @jnpdx, that is pretty much the intention, when the app launches I want to check token validity - I am not trying to preserve the login state here, rather verify the session is active on a server

Comment: Right -- you'd need to use some state management to get that to happen. At the least, `validSession` would need to be `@State`

Comment: Have you tried declaring `@State private var validSession = false` in your `LaunchView`. Currently you have `var validSession: Bool` is immutable

Comment: I fear your design has many obvious and also subtle flaws. Don't try to squeeze everything into a SwiftUI view. You are better off externalising all the login stuff. Note also, a client should treat a token as an opaque type - whether it's valid or not will be determined by the sever alone. Usually, a client would also never ask the server whether a token is valid, since the server might return "valid" but when used later on the server it might became invalid in the meantime, so it's useless.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, thanks for that input, I fear you didnt really read the code nor my explanation of it. This functions calls the server to determine token validity or direct the user to a login to get a new token. Some apps function differently :)

Comment: @unhep I apologise. Nonetheless, a viable solution would move the logic into a class conforming to ObservableObject. Internally it uses your keychain and token managers. This observable publishes the "view state", which includes everything  the view needs to render and may have "modes" (loading,  error, idle, etc). The view sends "intents" to the observable. Note, that you cannot use dispatch completion handlers in a SwiftUI View. Note, you may use the `task` modifier to start an async task when the view shows up - but I would not recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your variable with @State.

```
@State var validSession: Bool = false
```

Comment: I got this working by moving the onAppear logic to a .task and having the state bool in my initialised environment